# Can't figure out why my code dosen't work

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-room

I want to build a app like a Todo app that you can write to do things, and check them if they are done. And when finnished click the button deleteDoneTodos. But I got a problem when i click on the checkbox the values dont add up.
I want when I click on the checkbox to change value of my isChecked from 0 to 1, and if I click again value goes from 1 to 0. I want this beacuse I have a function that deletes all TextView's that have isChecked = 1.

Here is my code:

Todo.kt:

```
@Entity(tableName = "todo_table")
data class Todo (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int? = null,
    @ColumnInfo("title") val title: String?,
    @ColumnInfo("isChecked") var isChecked:Boolean = false
        )
```

TodoDao.kt:

```
@Dao
interface TodoDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insert(todo: Todo)

    @Query("DELETE FROM todo_table WHERE isChecked = 1")
    suspend fun deleteCheckedTodos()

    @Query("UPDATE todo_table SET isChecked = :checked WHERE id=:todoId")
    suspend fun update(todoId: Int?, checked: Boolean)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM todo_table WHERE id = :todoId")
    suspend fun getTodoById(todoId: Int?): Todo?


}
```

TodoAdapter.kt:

```
class TodoAdapter(
    private val todos: MutableList<Todo>
): RecyclerView.Adapter<TodoAdapter.TodoViewHolder>() {

    private val  appDb: AppDatabase = AppDatabase.getDatabase(App.instance)

    inner class TodoViewHolder(private val binding: ItemTodoBinding):
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){

                fun bind(todo: Todo){
                    val todoId: Int? = todo.id
                    binding.apply {
                        tvTodoTitle.text = todo.title
                        cbDone.isChecked = todo.isChecked
                        toggleStrikeThrough(tvTodoTitle, todo.isChecked, todo.id)
                        cbDone.setOnCheckedChangeListener{_, isChecked->
                            toggleStrikeThrough(tvTodoTitle, isChecked, todo.id)
                            todo.isChecked = isChecked
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

    private fun toggleStrikeThrough(tvTodoTitle: TextView, isChecked: Boolean, todoId: Int?){

        if(isChecked){
            tvTodoTitle.paintFlags = tvTodoTitle.paintFlags or Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
        }else{
            tvTodoTitle.paintFlags = tvTodoTitle.paintFlags and Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG.inv()
        }

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            todoId?.let {
                appDb.todoDao().update(todoId, isChecked)
            }
        }

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TodoViewHolder {
        val binding = ItemTodoBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)

        return  TodoViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return todos.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val curTodo = todos[position]
        holder.bind(curTodo)
    }

    fun addTodo(todo: Todo){



        GlobalScope.launch (Dispatchers.IO){
            appDb.todoDao().insert(todo)
        }
        todos.add(todo)
        notifyItemInserted(todos.size - 1)



    }

    fun deleteDoneTodos(){
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            appDb.todoDao().deleteCheckedTodos()
        }
        todos.removeAll { todo->
            todo.isChecked
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }


}
```

and MainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var todoAdapter: TodoAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        todoAdapter = TodoAdapter(mutableListOf())

        binding.rvToDoItems.adapter = todoAdapter

        binding.rvToDoItems.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        binding.btnAddToDo.setOnClickListener{

            val todoTitle = binding.etTodoTitle.text.toString()

            if(todoTitle.isNotEmpty()){
                val todo = Todo(null, todoTitle)
                todoAdapter.addTodo(todo)
                binding.etTodoTitle.text.clear()
            }
        }

        binding.btnDeleteDoneTodos.setOnClickListener {
            todoAdapter.deleteDoneTodos()
        }

    }
}
```